# CordovaBrowser app iOS - getting started with plugins example

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm trying to figure out how to get an accelerometer example working on the iPad using a local webserver and the [CordovaBrowser](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id573787308) app for iOS.

I believe that the CordovaBrowser app would have ALL the plugins built in to the native hosting application and that all I would need to do is include cordova.ios.js and all plugins would be available.

**When I browse to the page *from within the CordovaBrowser app*, I just get output that indicates that `navigator.accelerometer` is `null`.**

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>PhoneGap</title>
    <script src="js/cordova.ios.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="ts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Output">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is app.js:

```
$(function () {
    var output = $('#Output');

    try  {
        output.text('Loading ...');

        if(navigator) {
            output.text('Loaded Navigator ...');
        }

        if(navigator.accelerometer) {
            output.text('Loaded Accelerometer ...');
        }

        var watchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(function (acceleration) {
            output.text('Acceleration X: ' + acceleration.x + ', ' + 
                'Acceleration Y: ' + acceleration.y + ', ' + 
                'Acceleration Z: ' + acceleration.z + ', ' + 
                'Timestamp: ' + acceleration.timestamp);
        }, function () {
            output.text('Error!');
        }, {
            frequency: 300
        });
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

All the referenced js files are being loaded properly.  Is something else missing?

There's very little activity on the app's support site - which is a redirect to GitHub.  And based on the only Issue, that GitHub is only for Android, not the iOS version.  It could just be a bug in a new app, but it could also be that PhoneGap development has a lot of gotchas.

I'd use something else that promises a proper PhoneGap environment for arbitrary files.  I've used an app called [Hyperlab](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hyperlab/id525490328?mt=8) released last year that is pretty cool, but it isn't for iPad, has some quirks, and hasn't seen a single update.

I don't have/want a Mac and I don't want to pay $99 to fool with this.  Maybe later if we decide to go the route of developing a native app with PhoneGap.  Apple is ridiculous.

Comment: Mostly because I'm an idiot who didn't read carefully. Mea culpa. Now that I see "CordovaBrowser" I'm wondering if the app has been updated for iOS 6 support.

Comment: BTW, this is a 1st Gen iPad (I guess) and it's updates are maxed out at iOS 5.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an event listener for deviceready event and then start from there:

```
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

 function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the Cordova API
 }
```

Note: if you dont have a mac or you cannot test this on the actual device, you can use chrome to debug and test it and use chrome tools to change the accelerometer values.
Steps:

1- Right click on the page and click inspect element

2- on the right corner select settings

3- select overrides and override device orientation

NOTE: IF YOU ARE USING CHROME, THE DEVICE READY EVENT WILL NEVER GETS CALLED, SO YOU SHOULD CALL IT ON THE PAGE LOAD

Comment: I just now tried passing the top function definition to `document.addEventListener("deviceready", ..., false)` instead of `$(...)` but the `deviceready` seems to never fire.  (Again, this is in the CordovaBrowser testing utility app, in case that was overlooked.)

Comment: Im not sure how the "CordovaBrowser testing utility app" works, try chrome to see if you have any javascript issues/typo

Comment: if you can call onDeviceReady and then there is no navigator.accelerometer, i doubt that if the app has add <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="CDVAccelerometer" /> to config.xml

Comment: I think you forgot to add the Cordovo javascript library to your page, because once you add it, you will have access to all the methods, check out the latest build and make sure to follow the documentation.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.4.0/cordova_accelerometer_accelerometer.md.html#accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration_full_example

Answer (score -1):

The Cordova Accelerometer depends on a cordova library plugin which is only installed with a native app. Loading the JS in Safari will not have the same effect. You will have to use public JS APIs which are supported by iOS devices. I have [found one](http://www.murraypicton.com/2011/01/exploring-the-iphones-accelerometer-through-javascript/) that works with my iPad.

Comment: I'm not loading them into Safari, I'm loading them into an App called CordovaBrowser.  This is supposed to give full access to the Phonegap APIs, as it advertises.